# Keras model for multiclass classification is not learning for different parameters

Tags: r, multiclass-classification

I´m new to the area of Data Science and especially to the topic of modeling a neural network in RStudio.

I´m trying to do multiclass classification using a simple Keras dense network and predict 5 classes with it.
My total dataset is 12 input indicators for almost 35k instances (so 12x34961).
When I use the fit-function to train the model on 80% of the data over 100 epochs the loss is barely declining (1,57 to 1,55) and the accuracy stays level at 0.26.

So the model is not learning similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240629/loss-val-loss-acc-and-val-acc-do-not-update-at-all-over-epochs), but in my case, I don´t have a deep LSTM network and also using sigmoid as an activation function in the last layer did not improve the results.

[image: history of loss and accuracy over 100 epochs]

So far I have tried to play around with:

-using only a (small) subset of data

-changing "loss" and "optimizer"

-using a way more aggressive learning rate (SDG with lr=0.3)

-using deeper networks i.e. 6/7 layers with thousands of neurons

-using "class_weigth" argument to address the slight class imbalance

Here is the core code:

```
# Load data with 12 Input and one Output 
summary(data)

#############
# Categorise Output into five different classes
# L5 = 0-1
# L4 = 2-3
# L3 = 4-8
# L2 = 9-22
# L1 = 23+
# 
# for caution purposes manipulation is done in an extra dataframe
datatest <- data
names(datatest)[ncol(datatest)]<- "FC_3"
#
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3>=23, "L1"))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, (FC_3>=4 & FC_3 <= 8), "L3"))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3 ==2| FC_3==3, "L4"))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3 ==0| FC_3==1, "L5"))
datatest <- datatest %>%
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3 ==9, "L2"))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, (FC_3==11 | FC_3==10 | FC_3==12 | FC_3==13 | FC_3==14 | FC_3==15 | FC_3==16 | FC_3==17 | FC_3==18 | FC_3==19 | FC_3==20 | FC_3==21 | FC_3==22), "L2"))
#
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3=="L1", 1))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3=="L2", 2))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3=="L3", 3))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3=="L4", 4))
datatest <- datatest %>% 
  mutate(FC_3 = replace(FC_3, FC_3=="L5", 5))
#
data$ForwardCitations_3 <- as.numeric(datatest$FC_3)-1
# now the last column should be a numeric between 0 and 4, representing the actual classes
##
# beginn with Multiclass Classifiation

# Transform data into a matrix without names
data <- as.matrix(data)
dimnames(data) <- NULL

# Normalize the input
data[, 1:12] <- normalize(data[,1:12])
# summary(data)

# Data partition
set.seed(1235)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob = c(.8, .2))

training <- data[ind==1, 1:12]
test <- data[ind==2, 1:12]
trainingtarget <- data[ind==1, 13]
testtarget <- data[ind==2, 13]

# one Hot Encoding
trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainingtarget)
testlabels <- to_categorical(testtarget)

#Creating the sequential model
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units=48, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(12)) %>%
  # layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  # layer_dense(units=128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  # layer_dropout(rate = 0.16) %>%
  # layer_dense(units=32, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  # layer_dropout(rate= 0.8) %>% 
  # layer_dense(units=16, activation = 'relu') %>%
  # layer_dropout(rate= 0.8) %>% 
  # layer_dense(units=1024, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax')

# Compile
model %>%
  compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam', 
          metrics = 'accuracy')

# Fit model
history <- model %>%
  fit(training,
      trainLabels,
      epoch = 100,
      batch_size = 32,
      validation_split = .2
      # class_weight = list("0"= 2.507864, "1" = 1.483357, "2"=1.016865, "3" = 1, "4" = 1.180681)
  )
# plot(history)
```

I don´t know what the problem is, whether my code is actually doing what I´m trying to do and what I should try next.

PS: If you need further information I will be happy to provide it.