# Validation loss and loss stuck at 0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a classification problem with two labels to predict. For some reason, my validation_loss and my loss are always stuck at 0 when training. What could be the reason? Is there something wrong when calling loss functions? are they the appropriated ones for multi-label classification?

```
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=12, shuffle=True)
  X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=12, shuffle=True)

  model = keras.Sequential([
        #keras.layers.Flatten(batch_input_shape=(None,24)),
        keras.layers.Dense(first_neurona, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(second_neurona, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(third_neurona, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(fourth_neurona, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(), #WE NORMALIZE THE INPUT DATA 
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
        #keras.layers.BatchNormalization() #for multi-class problems we use softmax? 2 clases: Forehand or backhand 
    ])

  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


  history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batchSize, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
  test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

EDIT:
See the shape of my training data:

```
X_train shape : (280, 14) X_val shape : (94, 14) y_train shape : (280, 2) y_val shape : (94, 2)
```

the parameters when calling the function:

```
first neuron units:4
second neuron units: 8
learning rate= 0.0001
epochs= 1000
batch_size=32
```

also the metrics plots:

[image]

Comment: please print out shape of X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val. Also show value of number of neurons in each layer. Show model.fit printed output for a few epochs

Comment: Hi Gerry, I included what you said. See my edit. I amreally stuck with this and I do not understand why it is still stuck at 0. Could be some bad Keras parameter implemented?

Answer (score 1):

1. **softmax** activation fx should be the last step in *multiclass classification* - it converts logits to probabilities with no (non)-linearity transformations
2. pay attention to the output - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241789/15893581) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668150/15893581) advices helped me once -- in last layer you should have the same number of classes (**output_units**, here number of neurons) as the number of target classes in the training dataset -- because getting probabilities of belonging to each one class -- you then select *argmax* as most probable... and **for this reason** *one-hot* encoding apriori *model.fit()* is used for labels - in order to get at finish the slice of all probabilities per sample, from which you will choose  further *argmax* for this sample (as most probable)... OR use [sparse_categorical_crossentropy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69905584/15893581)
3. often on this trouble [is suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340876/my-loss-is-either-0-0-or-randomly-very-high-tensorflow) to decrease learning_rate - against *exploding gradients*
4. be carefull with activation='relu' & *vanishing gradient* - - use better  [Leaky ReLu or PReLU](https://localcoder.org/keras-neural-network-accuracy-is-always-0-while-training)  or use [gradient clipping](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340876/my-loss-is-either-0-0-or-randomly-very-high-tensorflow)
5. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707324/15893581) investigation also can matter

p.s. I can not test your data

Answer (score 0):

from the plot of validation accuracy it is clear it is changing so the loss must be changing as well. I suspect you are plotting the wrong values for loss which is why I wanted to see the actual model.fit printed training data. Make sure you have these assignments for loss'

```
val_loss=history.history('val_loss')
train_loss=history.history('loss')
```

also recommend you increase the learning_rate to .001

Comment: I am plotting exactly that. It seems the problem comes from the keras loss "categorical_crossentropy" because when I try with "binary crossentropy" it works.  I also tried with keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(name='categorical_crossentropy') and the same happens

Comment: Hmm strange your labels have the correct dimensions for categorical ie 2.  Are your y values integers or strings? If integer values 0 and 1 I can see why binary might work.